# conversion of XML to CSV in xslt

Tags: xslt

Hi i'm new to xslt style sheet. I have gone through all the posts that is converting XML to CSV file. But what i exactly needed is like below.

My XML data.

```
<EmployeeDetails>

<EmployeeName>ABC</EmployeeName>

<EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>

<EmployeeName>DEF</EmployeeName>

<EmployeeID>456</EmployeeID>

<EmployeeName>GHI</EmployeeName>

<EmployeeID>789</EmployeeID>

</EmployeeDetails>
```

And the output i need like

```
<Result>ABC,DEF,GHI</Result>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what tools you have available, but I wrote a simple function that does what you ask in c#.

```
 private void ProcessXML2(Object stateInfo)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data.xml", settings);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("<Result>");

        string xmlEmployeeName = String.Empty;

        reader.MoveToContent();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
               if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
               {
                    if (reader.Name == "EmployeeName")
                    {
                        while ((reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Text))
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                        }
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                            if (reader.Value != null)
                            {
                                sb.Append(reader.Value + ",");
                            }
                    }  
               }
        }

        sb.Append("</Result>");

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "output.csv"))
        {
            sw.Write(sb);
            sb.Clear();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

If you are able to use C#, you can tweak this method to be more clean. I have tested this with the input and output in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I wouln't call this csv, but the following stylesheet does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
 version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 >

<xsl:output method='xml' />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="EmployeeDetails"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="EmployeeDetails">
<Result><xsl:for-each select="EmployeeName">
<xsl:if test="position()&gt;1">,</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:for-each></Result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

$ xsltproc a.xsl b.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Result>ABC,DEF,GHI</Result>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit cleaner XSLT below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EmployeeDetails">
    <Result>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EmployeeName">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::EmployeeName">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EmployeeID"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```